# LeetCode: Add and Search Word C#

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, depth-first-search, trie

[This is a Leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/trie/148/practical-application-i/1052/):

> Design a data structure that supports the following two operations:
>
> - `void addWord(word)`
> - `bool search(word)`
>
> `search(word)` can search a literal
>   word or a regular expression string containing only letters `a-z` or `.`.
>   A `.` means it can represent any one letter.
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```
> addWord("bad") 
> addWord("dad")
> addWord("mad")
> search("pad") -> false
> search("bad") -> true
> search(".ad") -> true 
> search("b..") -> true
> ```
>
> **Note:**
>
> You may assume that all words consist of lowercase letters
>   a - z.

Here is my solution to this challenge:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace TrieQuestions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/trie/148/practical-application-i/1052/
    /// </summary>
    [TestClass]
    public class WordDictionaryTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void AddWordTest()
        {
            WordDictionary wordDic = new WordDictionary();
            wordDic.AddWord("cat");
            Assert.IsTrue(wordDic.Search("cat"));
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void SearchWordDoT()
        {
            WordDictionary wordDic = new WordDictionary();
            wordDic.AddWord("cat");
            Assert.IsTrue(wordDic.Search("c.t"));
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void SearchWordOne()
        {
            WordDictionary wordDic = new WordDictionary();
            wordDic.AddWord("a");
            Assert.IsTrue(wordDic.Search("."));
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void LeetCodeTest()
        {
            WordDictionary wordDic = new WordDictionary();
            wordDic.AddWord("bad");
            wordDic.AddWord("dad");
            wordDic.AddWord("mad");
            Assert.IsFalse(wordDic.Search("pad"));
            Assert.IsTrue(wordDic.Search("bad"));
            Assert.IsTrue(wordDic.Search(".ad"));
            Assert.IsTrue(wordDic.Search("b.."));
        }


        [TestMethod]
        public void LeetCodeTest2()
        {
            WordDictionary wordDic = new WordDictionary();
            wordDic.AddWord("at");
            wordDic.AddWord("and");
            wordDic.AddWord("an");
            wordDic.AddWord("add");
            Assert.IsFalse(wordDic.Search("a"));
            Assert.IsFalse(wordDic.Search(".at"));
            wordDic.AddWord("bat");
            Assert.IsTrue(wordDic.Search(".at"));
            Assert.IsTrue(wordDic.Search("an."));
            Assert.IsFalse(wordDic.Search("a.d."));
            Assert.IsFalse(wordDic.Search("b."));
            Assert.IsTrue(wordDic.Search("a.d"));
            Assert.IsFalse(wordDic.Search("."));
        }
    }

    public class WordDictionary
    {
        private TrieNode _head;
        /** Initialize your data structure here. */
        public WordDictionary()
        {
            _head = new TrieNode();
        }

        /** Adds a word into the data structure. */
        public void AddWord(string word)
        {
            var current = _head;
            foreach (var letter in word)
            {
                if (!current.Edges.TryGetValue(letter, out var output))
                {
                    output = current.Edges[letter] = new TrieNode();
                }
                current = output;
            }

            current.IsTerminal = true;
        }

        /** Returns if the word is in the data structure. A word could contain the dot character '.' to represent any one letter. */
        public bool Search(string word)
        {
            return Match(word, 0, _head);
        }

        private bool Match(string word, int i, TrieNode node)
        {
            if (i == word.Length)
            {
                return node.IsTerminal;
            }
            //if this is a regular letter check if it exists and mode on to the next letter
            if (word[i] != '.')
            {
                if (!node.Edges.ContainsKey(word[i]))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return Match(word, i + 1, node.Edges[word[i]]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //if we get a . try all of the different letters in recursion
                // if one of them returns true return true, there is a valid path to the next letter
                foreach (var currentNode in node.Edges)
                {
                    if (Match(word, i + 1, currentNode.Value))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Your WordDictionary object will be instantiated and called as such:
     * WordDictionary obj = new WordDictionary();
     * obj.AddWord(word);
     * bool param_2 = obj.Search(word);
     */
}
```

Please review my design and performance.

Comment: You should reuse the value of `word[i]`

Comment: There is a [Meta CR](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9257/why-was-this-answer-for-add-and-search-word-deleted-without-any-comments) question involving this post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short review: not a whole lot to say. I don't think breaking any of the method up any further would really help matters, and none of them should be combined, so the overall design looks reasonable to me.

### Documentation

I'm guessing the comments next to the methods are provided by the website: you should add proper inline documentation. Even if you are (for some reason) imposing a time limit on how long you spend designing and writing these programs, you should still go to the effort of documenting the API clearly, because it is a valuable skill itself. However, it's often a good idea to write the documentation before even implementing a method or class, so that you are forced to express precisely what it is to do (not how it will do it).

### Naming

I'm not overly fond of the name `output` in this line:

```
if (!current.Edges.TryGetValue(letter, out var output))
```

Output suggests it is outputted: it *is* outputted by `TryGetValue`, but that's `TryGetValue`'s problem: your problem is finding a descendent/child node.

`currentNode` is also a bit confusing: `node` is the 'current node', `currentNode` is a `KeyValuePair`. You might want to call it `child` and enumerate `node.Edges.Values`, since you don't need the keys.

I'm not sold on the name `Edges` either, since it isn't an arbitrary directed graph.

### Misc

- The spec says nothing about how to handle invalid data, but both `Match` and `AddWord` will throw a mysterious `NullReferenceException` when confronted with a `null`: much better to check throw a helpful `ArgumentNullException`.
- You might consider making `_head` `readonly`, which expresses the intention that it isn't going to change and prevents someone violating this assumption in the future.
- You might consider making `Match` static, since it doesn't need access to any state, which would make it easier to maintain because it will be easier to understand and harder to break.
- This comment is misleading: `// if one of them returns true return true, there is a valid path to the next letter`